# Al hacer print() de una variable obtenida por Entry, se imprime un espacio en blanco

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un "gestor" de BBDD para practicar un poco y me topé con un problema absurdo, el cual no tengo idea de por qué pasa.

Resulta que en un apartado se selecciona a traves de un Entry el nombre de la base de datos, el problema es que al querer obtener este nombre y pasarlo como variable simplemente no agarra nada. Pruebo haciendo prin() en la terminal y simplemente se imprime un espacio en blanco.

```
botonvalor= IntVar()

def connect():

 root3=Tk()
 root3.title("Conectar...")
 Label(root3, text="Introduce el nombre de la base").grid(row=0, column=0)

 nombre= StringVar()

 box=Entry(root3,textvariable=nombre)
 box.grid(row=1, column=0)

 boton2=Button(root3, text="Aceptar",command= botonvalor.set(1))
 boton2.grid(row=2, column=0)

 root3.wait_variable(botonvalor)

nombre2=nombre.get()
print(nombre2)

 root3.mainloop()
```

Con el código así directamente no me imprime nada, queda inerte por asi decirlo.

Pero sacando el command del botón y todo lo relacionado a la variable botonvalor, me imprime en blanco...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método que estás utilizando no le veo mucho sentido. También como recomendación, cuando estés trabajando con un tipo Input (Text, Entry...) crea una clase super para poder utilizar el método de [proxy](https://foroayuda.es/devolucion-de-llamada-modificada-de-texto-python-tkinter/) y obtener los cambios en su valor.

## Solución

Para este caso, la solución más lógica en la que he podido pensar ha sido en lo siguiente.

### Declarando widgets

Puedes ahorrarte mucho codigo a la hora de declarar el boton y el Entry Widget usando lo siguiente.

```py
def connect():
    root3=Tk()
    root3.title("Conectar...")
    Label(root3, text="Introduce el nombre de la base").grid(row=0, 
 column=0)

   box=Entry(root3)
   box.grid(row=1, column=0)

   boton2=Button(root3, text="Aceptar")
   boton2.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

### Obtención del input

Creamos una función para establecer la conexión. De argumento, el widget de texto. De esta forma conectando el comando del botón con la función mediante un lambda podremos obtener el valor del texto.

##### Implementar cuando se declara el botón

```py
 # Esta linea deberia ir en la función donde tienes el resto ---
 boton2=Button(root3, text="Aceptar",command= lambda input=box:establecerConexion(input))
 boton2.grid(row=2, column=0) 
 # ---

def establecerConexion(input):
  valor = input.get()
  # Tu codigo para la conexion aquí
```

##### Modificando el botón ya creado

```py
 # Esta linea deberia ir en la función donde tienes el resto ---
 boton2.configure(command= lambda input=box:establecerConexion(input))
 # ---

def establecerConexion(input):
  valor = input.get()
  # Tu código para la conexión aquí
```

Comment: Te agradezco un montón. Leyendo el codigo que habia puesto la verdad es ilogico, pasa que habia probado tanta cosa que ya me habia confundido.
Lo que si te queria preguntar, ¿Cual seria el entendimiento en lenguaje coloquial del "command" que usa el botón?

Es decir, si tuviese que formularlo en el lenguaje que hablamos normalmente, como lo desarrollarias? Porque lo veo y es como que entiendo pero no termino de conectar cada cosa.

Comment: @Kaster aquí la explicación. El command vendría siendo comando en español. Cuando el widget es activado el command es lo que le da la función que debe ser llamada y ejecutada. 

Algo importante a destacar es que no debes poner los parentesis al final de la funcion a no ser que estes usando el metodo de [lambda](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/expresiones-lambda-en-python/).

Comment: Sisi, lo del parentesis lo sabía, tengo entendido que si se pone sin el lambda el codigo se ejecuta sin interactuar con el widget. Igual me referia a la composición del command

O sea, de que manera interactua "input=box:conectar(input)"

No es por molestar, es para poder entenderlo y no copiar codigo por copiar.

Comment: Oooh, entiendo. Verás cuando se trata de lambda se debe declarar el valor a pasar. Por eso pongo "lambda input=box: conectar(input)", ya que primero indico que el valor de input es el boton y despues de los 2 puntos llamo a la función.

Comment: Ahhh perfectoo, te agradezco un montón enserio, me simplificaste todo y bueno, me tiraste un dato que seguramente me sirva mas adelante. Gracias de verdadd

Comment: No es nada, un placer haberte ayudado.